# How to release the memory used by a string on a map

Tags: c++

I have the declared two maps. First in each is a symbol. The outs maps the symbol to an ofstream, and the message_strs maps the symbol to a string which concatenates the messages received for the symbol. The objective is to store in the message_strs as many of the messages so as to reduce the number of times I have to write to file. I've tried both ways and this way is much faster. Here are the declerations:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> outs;
std::map<std::string, std::string> message_strs;
```

When the length of the string is large enough, (500000) I write it to the ofstream and the erase the string like this:

```
*outs[symbol] << message_strs[symbol];
message_strs[symbol] = "";
```

I am monitoring memory usage from task manager. I notice that when the write happens there's no reduction in my programs process memory. Do I have to do something in addition to just setting the string on the map to empty string to free the memory?

Comment: You can use `std::reference_wrapper<std::ofstream>` or `std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>`.

Comment: You might use [`std::string::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit), but it doesn't actually have to do anything.

Comment: You should not worry about that. Memory allocation algorithms usually never release memory to the OS, they just reuse it the next time you ask for it.

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod it's windows 7

Comment: it's quite normal that OS does not reclaim memory back from your process, as long as it doesn't need it. don't expet to see a change in values shown by task manager when you delete the big string from memory. at opposite, check used memory does not keep growing

Comment: _"I am monitoring memory usage from task manager."_ that is not a good measure of the memory your process has actually allocated.  Freeing memory doesn't promise what Windows will do with it.

Comment: Don't rely on task manager. this utility will give you a better idea of memory usage, but it is still aggregate. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx

Comment: @GianPaolo that's the problem, it keeps growing, and when usages is close to 2GB I get bad_alloc exception.

Comment: Well then you have a memory leak.

Comment: Instead of doing manual buffering via `message_strs` you may aswell try to increase buffer size of the stream: `std::ofstream::rdbuf()->pubsetbuf()`. Might be more effective, because the stream buffers anyway and you currently have the overhead of two buffering mechanisms.

Comment: Have you turned on DEBUG_NEW? You can also try using the Microsoft UMDH utility.

Comment: @zett42 can you show how to increase the buffer size to maximum? perhaps in an answer?

Comment: Example for using `pubsetbuf()` can be found in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf).

Answer (score 0):

Deallocations are generally handled in the C runtime, and not passed thrhough to the OS.